# Issues with compiling java using anotherEntry command

Tags: java, println

I am getting syntax errors when using the javac command when I try to input the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoVariables3
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
int entry;
Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an Integer");
entry = keyBoard.nextInt();
System.out.print("The entry is ");
System.out.println(entry);
System.out.print("Enter another integer ");
anotherEntry = keyBoard.nextInt();
System.out.print("The other entry is");
System.out.println(anotherEntry);
System.out.println(entry + " plus " +
anotherEntry + " is " + (entry + anotherEntry));
System.out.println(entry + " minus " +
anotherEntry + " is " + (entry - anotherEntry));
System.out.println(entry + " times " +
anotherEntry + " is " + (entry * anotherEntry));
System.out.println(entry + " divided by " +
anotherEntry + " is " + (entry / anotherEntry));
System.out.println("The remainder is " +
(entry % anotherEntry));
}
}
```

Here's my error msg:

```
C:\User\Student\Desktop\mywork>javac DemoVariables3.java
DemoVariables3.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(anotherEntry);
                   ^
```

That error message is repeated 12 times throughout my code; Any Help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I don't really see how anotherEntry isn't being defined, I thought that signifies what the end user puts in once I launch the application (I am just starting so I do apologize if I am wrong)

**Edit2**: God I feel stupid, I just didn't declare the string for anotherEntry; Thank You very much for pointing that out for me!